# Questions about feature selection and data engineering when using H2O autoencoder for anomaly detection

Tags: h2o, feature-selection, autoencoder, anomaly-detection, mse

I am using H2O autoencoder in R for anomaly detection. I don’t have a training dataset, so I am using the data.hex to train the model, and then the same data.hex to calculate the reconstruction errors. The rows in data.hex with the largest reconstruction errors are considered anomalous. Mean squared error (MSE) of the model, which is calculated by the model itself, would be the sum of the squared reconstruction errors and then divided by the number of rows (i.e. examples). Below is some sudo code of the model.

```
# Deeplearning Model

model.dl <- h2o.deeplearning(x = x, training_frame = data.hex, autoencoder = TRUE, activation = "Tanh", hidden = c(25,25,25), variable_importances = TRUE) 

# Anomaly Detection Algorithm 

errors <- h2o.anomaly(model.dl, data.hex, per_feature = FALSE)
```

Currently there are about 10 features (factors) in my data.hex, and they are all categorical features. I have two questions below:

(1) Do I need to perform feature selection to select a subset of the 10 features before the data go into the deep learning model (with autoencoder=TRUE), in case some features are significantly associated with each other? Or I don’t need to since the data will go into an autoencoder which compresses the data and selects only the most importance information already, so feature selection would be redundant?

(2) The purpose of using the H2O autoencoder here is to identify the senders in data.hex whose action is anomalous. Here are two examples of data.hex. Example B is a transformed version of Example A, by concatenating all the actions for each sender-receiver pair in Example A.

[image]

After running the model on data.hex in Example A and in Example B separately, what I got is

(a)   MSE from Example A (~0.005) is 20+ times larger than MSE from Example B;

(b)  When I put the reconstruction errors in ascending order and plot them (so errors increase from left to right in the plot), the reconstruction error curve from Example A is steeper (e.g. skyrocketing) on the right end, while the reconstruction error curve from Example B increases more gradually.

My question is, which example of data.hex works better for my purpose to identify anomalies?

Thanks for your insights!

Answer (score 1):

#### Question 1

You shouldn't need to decrease the number of inputted features into the model. I can't say I know what would happen during training, but collinear/associated features could be eliminated in the hidden layers as you said. You could consider adjusting your hidden nodes and see how it behaves. `hidden = c(25,25,25)` -> `hidden = c(25,10,25)` or `hidden = c(15,15)` or even `hidden = c(7, 5, 7)` for your few features.

#### Question 2

What is the purpose of your model? Are you trying to determine which "Sender/Receiver combinations" are anomalies or are you trying to determine which "Sender/Receiver + specific Action combo" are anomalies? If it's the former ("Sender/Receiver combinations") I would guess Example B is better.

If you want to know "Sender/Receiver combinations" and use Example A, then how would you aggregate all the actions for one Sender-Receiver combo? Will you average their error?

But it sounds like Example A has more of a response for anomalies in ascended order list (where only a few rows have high error). I would sample different rows and see if the errors make sense (as a domain expert). See if higher errors tend to seem to be anomaly-like rows.

Comment: Thanks Neema for the answers and good suggestions! Your questions about my 2nd question are something I need to think about.